# Pods in kubernetes, nearly identically deployed, one isn't visible

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, deployment

I am deploying an ASPNET Core REST api web service as a kubernetes pod. We use azure's kubernetes services and devops.

I have an already working ASPNET Core web server with some Blazor pages and such, and I have copied its build pipeline and deployment specification, and changed only the IP Address, and the name of the thing. These two projects also have virtually identical Docker files (The web server is .NET 6.0, and the REST api is .NET 7.0; that's about the only major difference, and to my knowledge it shouldn't be what prevents this from working.)

The two pods run on the same cluster, and use the same load balancer. There is a frontend IP configured for both of them. The IP I am using for my REST api is a 'defunct' one from an older deployment; I am replacing an older API with a newer implementation, the IP in question is intended for the test version of the old API, which is not currently deployed.

The problem is the web service works and is visible on the VPN IP address, but my new REST api is not. What am I doing wrong? How can I diagnose such a problem?